# Scrapyd-deploy command didn't take file from git submodules

Tags: git, python-3.x, scrapy, egg, scrapyd

everyone. I have issues.Here is my project structure:

```
+-- scraper  
|  +-- scraper  
|    +-- classification  
|    |  +-- classifier.py  
|    |  +-- .gitignore  
|    +-- helpers  
|    |  +-- help1.py  
|    +-- spiders  
|    |  +-- spider1.py
.gitignore
.gitmodule
scrapy.cfg
```

When I run command `scrapyd-deploy scraper -p scraper` - I haven't deployed dir `classification` This is git submodule that not deployed yet. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tree looks like it's missing `__init__.py` files. Without those files scrapyd will be unable to identify the packages.
All python packages need to contain `__init__.py` in their root directory. So your tree should look more like:

```
+-- scraper  
|  +-- scraper  
|    +-- __init__.py    <---
|    +-- classification  
|    |  +-- __init__.py    <---
|    |  +-- classifier.py  
|    |  +-- .gitignore  
|    +-- helpers  
|    |  +-- __init__.py    <---
|    |  +-- help1.py  
|    +-- spiders  
|    |  +-- __init__.py    <---
|    |  +-- spider1.py
|.gitignore
|.gitmodule
|scrapy.cfg
|setup.py   <---
```

And probably have a `setup.py` file for setup instructions as well.

Comment: In other words, he does not have python packages to be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped